# Scan Gun returning empty data in Python Script

Tags: python

I have a symbol barcode scanner model DS4308 that I am trying to pull scan data from.

In my python script, I am using the "hid" library via `import hid` to connect to the device. Here is the code block that is used to connect to the scanner:

```
    def initScanner(self):
        for device in hid.enumerate():
            if device['path'].endswith('hidraw6'.encode()):
                # Open the device
                h = hid.Device(path=device['path'])
                print("Initialized Scanner")
                return h

...
scanner = self.initScanner()
...
```

Which that part works and I am able to connect to the scanner. I then attempt to read the output from the scanner here:

```
        while True:
            barcode = scanner.read(64)
            if barcode:
                print(barcode)
```

While debugging, the script holds on `barcode = scanner.read(64)` which is expected as it's a blocking process. When I scan a test barcode, however, the output is always this:

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

I've tried multiple barcodes and they all return that same value.

I have no experience with programming barcode scanners, so I don't really know where to even start with this. I can't find any documentation or tutorials on how to program the scanner other than what is on the product page here: https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/scanners/general-purpose-scanners/ds4308.html#pageandfilelist_e56b

But I don't really understand any of what they are talking about in the manuals. Is there something more I need to do with the input from `scanner.read(64)` or something else I need to configure with the scanner to get it to work?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: so this would be a much better fit at SO unless you are pretty sure the issue is related to the input device installation.

Comment: @FrankThomas That's part of the issue. I don't know enough to know if its the scanner itself or the program. The program itself seems to work, in that it captures the scan event, but I don't know if there is some kind of configuration needed for the scanner or if the program is unable to decipher the scanner input.

Answer (score 0):

"Normally" the scanner creates keyboard input", so...

A simple python script that uses `v=input(...)` and then `print(v)` on the next line, should work just fine.

But then, you might have a reason to use `import hid`?

Does `hid` have support for Zebra scanners, actually stated?

Comment: I mainly need hid because each device will have multiple scanners and I need to know which scanner scans which barcode, so while input does work, I can't tell which device is actually inputting each value.

Comment: Does the Zebra DS4308 allow to prepend characters to what has been scanned? Datalogic has at least one that allow this, idea; prepending a "scanner-ID".